# Nodejs and require to include index.js file

Tags: node.js

I was reading around on Stack Overflow/Google and saw a method of including a js file for use of its contents in another file..

I have admin.js and index.js, in admin.js I need to access an array in index.js.

In index.js I have:

```
exports.chatrooms = function(){
    return usernames;
}
```

In admin.js I have:

```
var indexFileInclude = require('index.js');
var chatrooms = indexFileInclude.chatrooms();
console.log(JSON.stringify(chatrooms));
```

I get an error:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
Error: Cannot find module 'index.js'
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: Searching for a dupe... but the gist of it is, use relative paths to get to the files, for example, `./index.js`

Comment: If I change the file path to what you specified I get the error in use: Error: listen EADDRINUSE... As though something else is using port 3000

Comment: That's of course a different problem entirely.

Comment: Is it due to using http.listen(8080) in both files?

Comment: Yes, that would cause that error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `require()` if you do not specify a path it will assume you're targeting the node_modules folder. To instead pull a module in the same folder, you would use the `./` notation to specify you want to target the current folder.

```
var indexFileInclude = require('./index');
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! It is loading the file correctly now(I think...) as I am moving on to the next error, TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'chatrooms'. The method is 100% inside index.js simply returnning the array I need access to.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause that problem.